# Change chromium logo in new tab and remove experience icon

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I want to change chromium logo in new tab, I have also changed all product.icon files to something else but the new tab is still using chromium icon. Also I want to apply some changes on icons in the tool bar. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]